# iPhone Safari request doesn't send cookie

Tags: javascript, iphone, cookies, safari, request

Lets say I have an application on `foo.com` domain.

I am doing user authorization to `api.boo.com` using the `Fetch` method with credentials flag as `include` and CORS set as well.

After successful authorization I am getting a session cookie. I need that cookie to have an access to another API's methods on `api.boo.com` domain.

This flow works fine on almost every browser. The problem is on iPhone's Safari. Safari has default option (Settings -> Safari -> Block Cookies) setted as "Allow from Websistes I Visit" with this configuration Safari doesn't send the session cookie when I am calling another API's methods so it looks like I am unauthorized.

The simplest solution is to change the cookie policy to "Always Allow". After that a session cookie is being sent. However, I can't ask every user of my application to do that.

Do you have any ideas how to make this flow working properly on iPhone's Safari?